# How to get height of element in JQuery and use it in animate

Tags: jquery, animation

```
var oldHeight = $("#outerCart").height;
        $('#outerCart').animate(
                    { height: (oldHeight + 100) }, {
                        duration: 'slow',
                        easing: 'easeOutBounce'
                    });
```

Right now this code does not work (the culprit im guessing is putting oldHeight for the new Height). Putting a constant like this will work

```
var oldHeight = $("#outerCart").height;
        $('#outerCart').animate(
                    { height: 200 }, {
                        duration: 'slow',
                        easing: 'easeOutBounce'
                    });
```

How do i make this dynamic. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder if wrapping your "oldHeight" with parseInt would make a difference. That way you make sure that you are adding integers instead of a string plus an integer, which would fail!

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do `"+=100"` instead.

```
$('#outerCart').animate(
 { height: '+=100' }, {
     duration: 'slow',
     easing: 'easeOutBounce'
 });
```

From the docs for the [`animate()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method :

> Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with a leading += or -= sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property.

The reason your code didn't work was that you referenced the function without calling it.

```
$("#outerCart").height;
```

should have been:

```
$("#outerCart").height();
```